VPN connection seems to be up, but can't reach addresses that should be reachable through it
I have a .ovpn file which I use to create a VPN connection through the GUI assistant. The VPN connection works fine in Ubuntu 22.04 and I can reach the servers behind it, but connections just time out in 24.04. I am using SoapUI and the request just goes on forever until I have to cancel it. I'm happy to provide any command outputs.
